# Capture video in front camera

Tags: ios, camera, front-camera

Is it possible to capture a video using the front facing camera of an iPhone while there is a view that a user interacts with while the video is secretly recording? I am trying to develop a "proposal app" that will show a series of puzzle with a "Will you marry me" thing in the end, and as the user is playing the game the video recorder is running so it can capture the user's reaction while playing it. I am not worrying about the app getting accepted in the App Store since it will be used personally.

Answer (score 0):

Sure... but most probably to hide the recording preview you should digg into [AVFoundationFramework](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html). 
Before digg into it, I would check the UIImagePickerController class, maybe with a opaque [cameraOverlayView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView) view you can achieve what you want.
With AVFoundation you can do almost everything, but the user should grant explicitly the access to the camera and the microphone, the first time the app is in use.